# iPad turned itself off and won't turn back on

Tags: ipad, battery

I was just reading a webpage on my iPad and the screen went black and then the Apple logo came up and then the spinning loading wheel and it just went black...

Nothing after that.

The screen is blank/black/off - can't tell which. Resetting does nothing. Plugging it into the charge does nothing. Plugging it into iTunes does nothing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That sounds like behavior consistent with a dead battery. How long did you leave it plugged in?

I'd plug it in and leave it charging for 15+ minutes, then hold the home button and power button simultaneously for 10 seconds to do a hard reset. If that doesn't work, it's off to the Apple Store to get a new one.

Comment: Oddly enough, I needed to do a hard reset even without a bad battery.  Helpful

Answer (score 3):

Try holding the home and power button for 45 seconds or so... (be patient!)

If you are lucky like I was, then your iPad will "come back to life".

Answer (score 0):

I have the best solution to this. Follow this 3 steps and you will enjoy back your iDevice.

1. Put your iDevice on a DFU or Recovery Mode while connected to power on the wall. Visit Youtube to learn how to put your iDevice on Recovery Mode.
2. After yours is on a DFU or Recovery Mode, simply allow your iDevice to charge overnight.
3. After several hours of your iDevice charging on a DUF or Recovery Mode, turn it on from DUF or Recovery Mode to its normal mood. This can be done by simply holding both the power button and the home button till you see the Apple logo. Then turn the device off for it to fully charge.

Lesson: never use or allow your device to run on a red battery before charging.  Enjoy! Works 100%.